# Analytic Solutions To Matrix Differential Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

Given the matrix differential equation: $\frac{d U(t)}{dt} = A(t) U(t)$ and the fact that $A_t$ is comprised only of analytic functions Is it possible to conclude that the solution $U(t)$ will be analytic also? I'd appreciate a reference for this, thanks.

Comment: Search Cauchy–Kowalevski theorem

Comment: Is the any way to learn about the radius of convergence of the solution? For which times does this theorem imply the existence of an analytic solution?

Comment: For example, what property of $A_t$ would I need to guarantee some given radius of convergence $r \in \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: If all elements of $A$ are entire functions, then $U$ is entire function too. I cannot prove it right now, but it seems obvious.

Comment: It seems obvious to me too! I just can't show it!